# unwind list in pymongo group statement

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm following the example at: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html to produce a grouped list, but the issue I have is that the field I am interested in, might need to be unwound, as its a list, but I don't see a smart way to do this. I.e. where should I place the `$unwind` statement?

```
results = mongo.db.courses.group({"$unwind": "institution"}, key={"institution":1 }, condition={}, initial={"count": 0}, reduce=reducer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the aggregation pipeline?

```
pipeline = [
     {"$unwind": "$institution"},
     {"$group": .... }
 ]
results = mongo.db.courses.aggregate(pipeline)
```

Comment: can I still get the counts out?

Comment: sure. using $sum operator https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/